# HoloLens holographic app

Tags: hololens

When you use the "Holographic DirectX 11 App" template in Visual Studio, it creates an app that occupies the entire HoloLens view (I believe it's call the Holographic View).

How do you build a Holographic App like the Hologram demos where you can re-size the box and place the app in the Holographic Shell?

BTW, can someone with a higher reputation create a new tag "hololens-directx". I think there are beginning to be more DirectX development and this would help distinguish from the Unity questions.

Comment: Please mark a response as the answer if it properly answers your question.

Answer (score 4):

Short Answer: Not Yet

Microsoft is reserving development right such as this as well as [live tiles](https://www.onmsft.com/news/microsoft-granted-patent-3d-live-tiles). Of the many forum posts regarding this, an official Microsoft team has formally responded to this one below.

[image]

To understand more options available to you in your app development, see this page about the [app model](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/app_model).

Answer (score 1):

The ability to place holograms into the Holographic Shell is not exposed to app developers.

Hologram app is an inbox app and third party apps cannot replicate this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

App developers can only place GLTF model into Shell as a link to their app.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/uapmanifestschema/element-uap5-mixedrealitymodel